# Can QCoreApplication::exec() be replaced with a while() loop?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, ffi, event-loop

I'm working on QML bindings for a programming language using `QGuiApplication` and `QQmlApplicationEngine`. I need a way to replace exec() with a while() loop so that I can still process events.

Basically, instead of

```cpp
QGuiApplication app;
app.exec();
```

I want something like:

```cpp
QGuiApplication app;
while (true) {
    app.processEvents();
    if (app.windowClosed()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with FFI acronym, maybe it should be FFT? Anyway I suspect you should just use `QThread` if you provide more context (how this FFI is used) I will show you how to do it in proper way.

Comment: @MarekR FFI means Foreign Function Interface. I added that to the description.

Comment: How does this FFI related to the question and to the code you've provided? Can you explain what exactly do you want to do?  To add your function into the main loop? I think this is a bad idea. What if your code will bock? will be executed too long time? Just run your code inside a separated thread.

Comment: But if you indend to cal this so called "FFI" in `doWork()` it will block the event processing too... You obviously should go for threading your code.

Comment: @folibis the doWork() was just an example of what I was trying to do: replace a blocking exec() call that never returns. I removed all references to doWork() and FFI. They aren't really relevant.

Comment: But in fact you're trying to reinvent the wheel. I don't know what `QApplication::exec` really does but I think that more or less the same as you want to do, so why rewrite it? To break the `exec()` just call to `QCoreApplication::exit()`